# How to run an operator on UILayout.prop changes

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have a UILayout.prop(object, 'rotation_euler') to rotate the active object, a UILayout.prop(object, 'rotation_quaternion') and an operator to update the object rotation_quaternion property.

```
 
class USER_PT_RotationUtilities(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Rotation utilities"
    bl_idname = "ANT0_PT_RotationUtilities"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'MyTools'
    bl_context = 'objectmode'

    def draw(self, context):
        obj = context.object
        layout = self.layout
        
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text="Rotation Euler (XYZ)")
        row = box.row()
        row.use_property_split = True
        row.prop(obj, "rotation_euler", text="") # upon property update I need to call
                                                 # the USER_OT_RotationUpdateQuaternion operator 
        
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text="Rotation Quaternion")
        row = box.row()
        row.use_property_split = True
        row.prop(obj, "rotation_quaternion", text="")


class USER_OT_RotationUpdateQuaternion(bpy.types.Operator): 
    bl_label = "Update quaternion rotation"
    bl_idname = "object.ru_update_quaternion"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # here quaternion update code
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I need to execute the operator upon rotation_euler property updates to synchronize the rotation_quaternion property.

Is it possible?

Comment: Refer to [Message Bus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) (Blender docs.)